# Spring boot MySQL request return null when it shouldn't

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm making a rest API for an App I'm creating,
I have a MySQL database and I'm using Springboot.
I coded this

```java
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MySQLInfosGateway implements InfosGateway {
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public MySQLInfosGateway(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
        this.jdbcTemplate=jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public Personne getInfos(String badge){
        var query = "select NOM, PRENOM from PERSONNEL where BADGE = "+badge;
        var result = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new ResultSetExtractor<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                resultSet.next();
                return new Personne(resultSet.getString("NOM"),resultSet.getString("PRENOM"));
            }
        });
        return (Personne) result;
    }
}
```

Here's my `Personne`class :

```
package com.piroux.phoenixrhbackend.domain.entities;

public class Personne {
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;

    public Personne(String nom, String prenom){
        this.nom=nom;
        this.prenom=prenom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
}
```

and I'm trying with the following request on Postman:

`localhost:8080/fonction-recup-infos/nom-prenom?badge=50387`

If I execute the request `select NOM, PRENOM from PERSONNEL where BADGE = 50387`

- In a SQL script => I get the correct `NOM` and `PRENOM`;
- With my API => I get `null` and `null`

For you to know, `BADGE` is a **unique** String, so there's **only one** NOM and PRENOM for each BADGE.

It's my first time creating a REST API so if any information is missing please tell me

Comment: how did you instantiate your gateway?

Comment: @Stultuske 
`@Bean
public InfosGateway infosGateway(){return new MySQLInfosGateway(jdbcTemplate);}`

Comment: *var query = "select NOM, PRENOM from PERSONNEL where BADGE = "+badge;* - show the value of `query` variable after. *BADGE is a unique String* String literal value must be enclosed with quote chars. Test `var query = "select NOM, PRENOM from PERSONNEL where BADGE = '"+badge+"'";`

Comment: @Akina I ran in debug and I got 
`query = "select NOM, PRENOM from PERSONNEL where BADGE = 50387"`
which is exactly what I want it to be

Comment: Could you also add your `Personne` class. The error might be in there as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum I added it to the question

Comment: why are there no getters/setters in there?

Comment: @Stultuske I thought `nom` and `prenom` where in public but it seems I put them as private, I now added the getters and setters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things wrong with your code. First **never** use concatenation to create a query string based on user input. It is dangerous. Second I would suggest using the `RowMapper` instead of the `ResultSetExtractor` it is easier to use.

You are using `getString("<column-name>")` if your database doesn't expose the metadata this won't work and you have to use positional identifiers.

All in all I suggest you do this.

```java
@Override
public Personne getInfos(String badge){
    var query = "select NOM, PRENOM from PERSONNEL where BADGE = :badge";
    var result = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, Map.of("badge", badge), (rs, rowNum) -> 
    new Personne(rs.getString("NOM"), rs.getString("PRENOM"));        
    return result;
}
```

**NOTE:** You also might want to try `nom` and `prenom` as the column names, yuo are using MySQL which can be a bit picky about casing (depending on your configuration of MySQL and the platform you are running on).

Comment: I tried your solution;
but I get an error on the **jdbcTemplate.query*. It tells me `no suitable method found for query(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,(resultSet[...]OM")))`
Plus the `getString` method of rs is in red but I don't know what's wrong with it

Comment: You looked at my old answer, I changed `query` to `queryForObject` which is the correct one) as well as the change in the signature (it needs another parameter for the lambda) and it needs parameters in the other way.

Comment: I Still get the same kind of problems :
queryForObject is underline in red and it shows `Cannot resolve method 'queryForObject(java.lang.String, <lambda expression>)'`

and `rs.getString` is still in red and i can "_rename reference_" but it doesn't change anything 
*EDIT* : plus result type is now void

Comment: A crap my bad. You are using the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` and not the `JdbcTemplate`. Updated (again).

Comment: Now It works; I check in debug mode; figured out My original code worked and the error was elsewhere. In fact I didn't return the right Object in another method of anorther class. But anyway, thanks for your help as now my code is cleaner than before :D

Answer (score 0):

Change this line from

```
 var query = "select NOM, PRENOM from PERSONNEL where BADGE = "+badge;
```

to

```
 var query = "select NOM, PRENOM from PERSONNEL where BADGE = '" + badge + "'";
```

It might be resolved.

Comment: I tried, but I still have null and null

Comment: let check something, modify sql by `var query = "select 1 as abc, NOM, PRENOM from PERSONNEL where BADGE = '" + badge + "'";`

and modify this line `var result = jdbcTemplate.query(query, badge, (rs) -> 
                new Personne(rs.getString("NOM"), rs.getString("PRENOM"));  ` by

`var result = jdbcTemplate.query(query, badge, (rs) -> 
                System.out.println(rs.getString("abc"));
                new Personne(rs.getString("NOM"), rs.getString("PRENOM"));  `

Can you get the '1'?

Comment: I tried ; but I get an error on the *jdbcTemplate.query*. It tells me no suitable method found for query(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,<lambda expression>)) Plus the getString method of rs is in red but I don't know what's wrong with it

Comment: Oh sorry, My mistake. The code should be look like this
`
jdbcTemplate.query(query, badge, (rs) -> {
System.out.println(rs.getString("abc"));                 new Personne(rs.getString("NOM"), rs.getString("PRENOM"));
}                 
`

Comment: Still the same problem : `no suitable method found for query(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,(rs)->{ Sy[...])); })`